# Add second keyboard layout with localectl

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout, localectl

I am using Fedora 28 workstation with Gnome.

My current layout status with `localectl status` is

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

I am using

```
localectl set-x11-keymap "us,gr" "" ","
```

in order to add second (greek) layout. New `localectl status` result is

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us,gr
     X11 Variant: ,
```

but when I press super(key) + space, no greek characters are displayed.

How can I add a second keyboard layout with command line?

I have a fresh install of Fedora 28 Workstation. Selected language and keyboard layout are "US".

I am trying to add a second language in the keyboard but not from Gnome (i.e. Settings->Region & Language-> Input Source), but from the command line.

I am using localectl; when I use set-keymap, I can write greek characters on the login screen but not in a terminal.

I am trying set-x11-keymap and I can't write greek characters -- only US.

When I enter the simple command

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us,gr
```

in the login screen the language selector is present. But AFTER I log in, there is no language selector in the taskbar!?!?!

I then made a clean install.

Step 1: before I make anything, I execute `setxkbmap -print` and I get

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Step 2: I execute the following command

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,gr" -option "grp:win_space_toggle"
```

Step 3: now I am trying to press win+space keys but I can't print greek characters.

Step 4: the output of `setxkbmap -print` is now

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+gr:2+inet(evdev)+group(win_space_toggle)"};
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

I logged out and there is no language selector on login screen. Also: after I log in, I can write only English characters.

Comment: Fedora 28 has **long** been unsupported. It's not advisable to continue using it.

Comment: I tried the same procedure on Fedora 31. No luck also there... If you know the solution to any version, please answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

From phone now and memory. IOW I've not tried these below suggestions though I've tried v similar.
See this old thread of mine replacing "apl" by "gr"
http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/APL-mode-td299716i40.html

## Use setxkbmap

### chord-based using alt

```
  $ setxkbmap -layout "us,gr" -option "grp:switch"
```

## Using ralt

Leave lalt alone

```
   $ setxkbmap -layout "us,gr"  -option "grp:rswitch"
```

### Toggle based solution

alt-shift switching to gr and back

```
   $ setxkbmap -layout "us,gr" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Comment: I tried them all. None seems to be working... :-(. I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ger3rsRkJ-Y but i don't understand French

Comment: Not working means? Nothing happens? Error message? You need to start some kind of editor and then type left-alt+a as a chord to get greek alpha (1st solution). Should add though that I've not used a red hat system for 25 years.... Above is on ubuntu. Also try the examples in the emacs thread I've linked and see if you get APL chars (many straight greek, some math)

Comment: Basically check first that setxkbmap (instead of localectl)  works on your system. Then see how to make it work usefully for you

Comment: A basic question @chris : Do you have the command setxkbmap on your system? If so what does setxkbmap -print give? ( Before and after above commands)

Comment: Yes setxkbmap is present. The result of the print command is xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
 xkb_types     { include "complete" };
 xkb_compat    { include "complete" };
 xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
 xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
 BUT I want to use localectl.

Comment: I tried setxkbmap -layout us,gr  -variant ,      I logged out and in the login screen the language selector is present with greek and English. But after I logged in the language selector is disappeared and I can't write in greek

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111819/discussion-between-rusi-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can run (restarting the Xorg server or rebooting is **required** afterwards):

```
sudo localectl set-x11-keymap "us,gr" pc105 "" grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:win_space_toggle,grp_led:scroll,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,ctrl:nocaps
```

<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> - will switch the keyboard layout between US and Greek keyboards. <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> will be disabled. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> can be used to kill/restart X.org.

You **must** disable Gnome specific keyboard configuration to make the above command work properly - it actually edits an X.org configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` to be precise.

Comment: @"Artem S. Tashkinow" I tried the command. localectl status nows presents 
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us,gr
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:win_space_toggle,grp_led:scroll,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,ctrl:nocaps but when i press super+space or left alt + shift only English characters are typed

Comment: It indicates everything works for you. Try **rebooting**. It does **not** work on the fly.

Comment: I rebooted the system. I just forget to write it above

Comment: Do you have a Scroll Lock LED? Does it light up when you press Alt + Shift or Win + Space? Again Gnome can redefine keyboard settings, so you may want to stop Gnome from doing that. I've no idea how since I use XFCE.

Comment: Yes scroll lock is lighting when i press super + space. I redefined toggle input (super +w) but nothing happened! I believe the problem is that there is no language selector in taskbar after I login .

Comment: Please create a separate/new user account and log in under it. This will allow to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work if you don't mind running it on every boot

`setxkbmap -layout us, gr -options grp:win_space_toggle`